# OpenAPI generator returns 501 for implemented method

Tags: spring, openapi-generator, default-method

I've generated rest api with openAPI generator maven plugin and I've overridden the default method from `MyApiDelegate` interface, but POST request on `/endpoint` provides 501 NOT IMPLEMENTED as if I hadn't given my own implementation of that method in MyApiDelegateImpl.

Maven plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <configOptions>
   <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/latest.yaml</inputSpec>
                            <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                            <apiPackage>my.rest.api</apiPackage>
                            <modelPackage>my.rest.model</modelPackage>
                       <supportingFilesToGenerate>ApiUtil.java</supportingFilesToGenerate>
                                <delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>
                                <useBeanValidation>false</useBeanValidation>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
</plugin>
```

```
/* code generated by plugin */
package my.rest;
public interface MyApiDelegate {
    default Optional<NativeWebRequest> getRequest() {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    default ResponseEntity<Void> doSmth(Smth smth) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
    }

}

package my.rest.api;
public interface MyApi {
    default MyApiDelegate getDelegate() {
        return new MyApiDelegate() {};
    }

    /*...Api operations annotations...*/
    @RequestMapping(value = "/endpoint",
        produces = { "application/json" }, 
        consumes = { "application/json", "application/xml" },
        method = RequestMethod.POST)
    default ResponseEntity<Void> doSmth(@ApiParam(value = "" ,required=true) @RequestBody Smth smth) {
        return getDelegate().doSmth(smth);
    }

}
```

my implementation:

```
package my.rest.api;
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyApiDelegateImpl implements MyApiDelegate {
    private final MyService s;

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<Void> doSmth(Smth smth) {
        s.doIt(smth);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
}
```

How can I make my program use my own implementation of the method in concrete class, not the **default** implementation, which is provided in interface?

Answer (score 1):

Implementing the `MyApi` interface directly and hence the method `doSmth`
in it, is one way of doing that. Your concrete class need not have all the web related annotations but just the paramters and return value like a normal method.

I don't understand how can an interface `MyApiDelegate` can be initialized but since `getDelegate` returns an implementation of it, the default implementation of `doSmth` is called which returns `HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED`.

One more thing to take care of is making sure the deployment knows to use the implementation class. If you're using spring web than just marking your concrete class *@RestController* should suffice.

Comment: since openAPI generator uses Delegate DP, the purpose of the default method in MyApi interface is just to call the appropriate service, thus it does not solve my problem. Due to openAPI generator plugin annotation Controller is enough. The thing I really don't understand is why my class uses the default implementation in the interface even though I've created a concrete class with a method that overrides it.